# Substitute 25mM dNTPs mix with 10mM dNTPs

Tags: biochemistry, molecular-biology, lab-techniques, lab-reagents

I need to make a solution of multiple compounds, one of them is dNTPs. The recipe calls for 20 μl 25 mM dNTPs in a 1250 μL master mix. Unfortunately I do not have it available at that concentration, can I substitute 25mM dNTP mix with 10mM mix?

TECHNICAL DETAILS

- $dATP: C_{10}H_{13}N_5O_{12}P_3Na_3 - MW=557.2$
- $dCTP: C_9H_{13}N_3O_{13}P_3Na_3 - MW=533.1$
- $dGTP: C_{10}H_{13}N_5O_{13}P_3Na_3-MW=573.2$
- $dTTP: C_{10}H_{14}N_2O_{14}P_3Na_3-MW=548.1$

Would it be 50μL of 10mM dNTPs to substitute the 20μL of 25mM dNTPs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can do this. As long as the final mix has the proper concentrations of everything, its fine. Just make sure you compensate the by adding 30 uL (the extra volume) less of water to the master mix.